# Is the Grand Priest the father of the angels biologically, or religiously, or both?

Tags: dragon-ball

Is the Grand Priest the father of the angels biologically or religiously or both?

The title "Priest" seems to imply that it is religious, but seeing as how their abilities are the same, and abilities are passed down genetically as seen through all of the characters in the entire *Dragon Ball* series (i.e. Saiyans and their zenkai boosts).

So is the Grand Priest the father to the angels biologically or religiously?

Answer (score 1):

The Grand Priest is the biological father of the angels. Early on in Super, Whis comments that the rest of the angels are his siblings - you can see that panel with translation [here](https://twitter.com/strawhatcrt/status/1002348419933851648/photo/1).

An approximate translation of the dialog is:

> Supreme Kai: By the way, are all the angels your siblings?
>
> Whis: Yes, that's correct. Kusu, from Universe 10, is the oldest.

Much later in Super, in epsiode 67, Whis has a conversation with Grand Priest where he calls him his father (using "otou-sama", a term for familial relationships). You can see that [here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x52v0an), at about 1:30 in:

> Grand Priest: Oh, I envy Universe Seven.
>
> Whis: Please, come visit [the universe] sometime, father.

If Whis is Grand Priest's son and the other angel's siblings, it stands to reason Grand Priest is the rest of the angels' biological parent as well.